# Why can't Resharper resolve my angular 2 imports?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, resharper

I've just been fiddling around with some Angular 2 related stuff in VS2015 and I can't figure out why Resharper can't deal with these resolves.

[image]

The top bit where you can see the signature of platformBrowserDynamic is coming from Visual Studio, whereas Resharper is marking it red and saying it can't find it. It's extremely distracting and breaks all the intellisense as well.

If I disable Resharper there's no problem at all. Visual Studio gives me all the proper tips and intellisense, but then of course I lose all the benefits of Resharper.

This project also has no problems building and running so clearly there's some kind of problem with Resharper here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which ReSharper version do you use? Looks like a bug that was fixed in 2016.2.2.

Comment: Yeah, I updated to 2016.2.2 and it fixed most of it. There's still some lingering issues with resolving references so at this point in time Resharper still seems pretty broken for this use case.

Comment: can you solve now ?

Answer (score 1):

This is provably not the best solution but it provides a workaround

Error:
Symbol 'X' can not be properly resolved, probably its located in an inaccessible module

Solution:
You can disabled resharper’s typescript inspection for now.
In VS2015 go to Resharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings
Find ‘File masks’ (bottom right) and add *.ts

With this you will maintain all the resharper functionalities while disable it for TypeScript

This is the full [article](http://www.jomendez.com/2016/11/07/angularjs-2-seed-visual-studio-2015/) on how to install angular 2 seed for VS 2015:

Comment: This worked for me in 2017 (although I'm not happy there's not a better solution)